# jquery code improvemt. Hover Function, i try to retrieving information about a value in the first function

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

i'am a learner so i need still experience and i have many questions, but today i have only one question about the hover function.

is it possible to send the information about a variable from the first hover function into the seconde one? i think you dont need more information. is just changing a part from the src in a  tag.

i hope you understand me. =)

here is the example

http://jsbin.com/eporib/edit#javascript,html,live

how is look now!

```
box.hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
                oldImg = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
                slicedOldImg = oldImg.slice(0,-5),
                newImg = slicedOldImg+num6;
    $this.find('img').attr('src', newImg);
      $('#hello').append('IN '+newImg);

}, function() {
              var $this = $(this),
                  oldImg = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
                  slicedOldImg = oldImg.slice(0,-5),
                  newImg = slicedOldImg+num1;
    $this.find('img').attr('src', newImg);
            $('#hello').append('OUT '+newImg+ '<br />');

}); /*end Hover*/
```

and how i want it

```
box.hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
                oldImg = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
                slicedOldImg = oldImg.slice(0,-5),
                newImg = slicedOldImg+num6;
    $this.find('img').attr('src', newImg);
      $('#hello').append('IN '+newImg);

}, function() {
    $this.find('img').attr('src', oldImg);
          //look here, the oldImg is in the first function.
          // and i want it use it in the second too.

            $('#hello').append('OUT '+newImg+ '<br />');

}); /*end Hover*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are at least two ways you can do this:

#### 1. Using a closure

Wrap the whole thing in a closure and use a variable in that closure:

```
(function() {
    var oldImg;

    box.hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this), slicedOldImg newImg;
        oldImg = $this.find('img').attr('src'); // Setting it
        slicedOldImg = oldImg.slice(0,-5);
        newImg = slicedOldImg+num6;
        $this.find('img').attr('src', newImg);
          $('#hello').append('IN '+newImg);

    }, function() {
        // Missing `var $this = $(this);` here?
        if (oldImg) {
            // Use it
            $this.find('img').attr('src', oldImg);

            // and clear it
            oldImg = undefined;
        }

        $('#hello').append('OUT '+newImg+ '<br />');

    }    ); /*end Hover*/
})();
```

In that example, we use an anonymous wrapper function that we execute immediately for the closure, but you may well already be doing this code in a closure (a function), so you may not need to add that wrapper. (If the word "closure" is new to you, don't worry, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)

#### 2. Using `data`

Alternately, you can use `data` to store the information on the element:

```
box.hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
                oldImg = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
                slicedOldImg = oldImg.slice(0,-5),
                newImg = slicedOldImg+num6;
    $this.data("oldImg", oldImg);
    $this.find('img').attr('src', newImg);
      $('#hello').append('IN '+newImg);

}, function() {
    // Missing `var $this = $(this);` here?
    var oldImg = $this.data("oldImg");
    if (oldImg) {
        $this.find('img').attr('src', oldImg);
        $('#hello').append('OUT '+newImg+ '<br />');
    }    
}    ); /*end Hover*/
```

Comment: I would probably recommend the data method since it would be more accessible for other developers on a team.

Comment: hey, thx for replies.
http://jsbin.com/enufoy/4/edit
heres a codeexample for the closures. it doesnt function. the var oldImg is undefined in the mouseout function. for me, its sounds better than the data storing in the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing some extra data in `.data()` property:

```
box.hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
                oldImg = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
                slicedOldImg = oldImg.slice(0,-5),
                newImg = slicedOldImg+num6;

          $this.data('slicedOldImg', slicedOldImg);

    $this.find('img').attr('src', newImg);
          $('#hello').append('IN '+newImg);

}, function() {
    $this.find('img').attr('src', oldImg);
          //look here, the oldImg is in the first function.
           and i want it use it in the second too.
                var slicedOldImg = this.data('slicedOldImg');
                var newImg = slicedOldImg+num1;

            $('#hello').append('OUT '+newImg+ '<br />');

}); /*end Hover*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery´s [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) inside your hover-in function to save `oldImg` at the img-Element:

```
$this.find('img').data('oldImg', oldImg);
```

The information is saved within the DOM tree, so you can access it from your hover-out function:

```
var oldImg = $this.find('img').data($img, 'oldImg');
```

PS: Maybe it is more robust to perform the saving at document init and not at the Hover-Event...